# Chart.js doughnut type chart labels overlap on the chart

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, charts

I am having a problem with chart.js and a doughnut type chart. I want to apply some offset/margin or other solution for the margin between chart and labels.  Please view the below image for the issue.

[image]

```
 var chart1;
    var config1 = {
        type: 'doughnut',
        data: {
            labels: ["NPD Brief", "Gate 1", "Gate 2", "Gate 3"],
            datasets: [{
                data: [2, 3, 5, 4], // Specify the data values array 
                borderColor: ['#ffffff', '#ffffff', '#ffffff', '#ffffff'], // Add custom color border 
                backgroundColor: ['#2453ed', '#5b7ef2', '#91a9f6', '#c8d4fa'], // Add custom color background (Points and Fill)
                borderWidth: 2 // Specify bar border width
            }]
        },
        options: {
            responsive: true,
            maintainAspectRatio: false, // Add to prevent default behaviour of full-width/height 
            legend: {
                display: false,
                position: 'left',
            },
            plugins: {
                labels: [{
                    render: 'label',
                    position: 'outside',
                    //arc: true,
                }, {
                    render: 'value',
                    fontColor: '#ffffff',
                }]
            },
            title: {
                display: true,
                //text: 'Chart.js Doughnut Chart'
            },
            animation: {
                animateScale: true,
                animateRotate: true
            }

        }
    };
```

Comment: Need some padding between chart and labels, so the label does not overlap.

Comment: What version of chart.js?

Comment: @natel chart.js version is: 1.1.0

Comment: Here's a jsfiddle with version 1.0.1.  https://jsfiddle.net/cmyker/u6rr5moq/ Maybe that helps?

Comment: @natel Thanks for your effort but i need only padding between chart and label.

Comment: I am getting like this - http://jsfiddle.net/sarunuk/qyxvh4fs/  Could you please include your changes here ?